# Recursion Maze in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm reading a maze from a text file where I'm using the '@' as the bread crumb to navigate the maze using recursion. It reads and prints just fine, but when I added the actual logic it goes wrong. I'm not sure if I'm not understanding recursion I know it calls itself until the base case is met (the E/exit) I'm having some errors that pop  up saying I have syntax error with my '@' but there is no red line( I'm using Visual Studios)  also it says

> Error  1   error C2660: 'mazeEscape' : function does not take 2 arguments

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
const int ROWS = 10;
const int COLS = 10;

bool mazeEscape(char maze[ROWS][COLS],int row,int col)
{

    bool result = false;

    if (row < 0 || row >= ROWS || col < 0 || col >= COLS)
        return false;

    if (mazeEscape(row - 1, col))   // recursively move up
        result = true;
    else if (mazeEscape(row + 1, col)) // recursively move down
        result = true;
    else if (mazeEscape(row, col - 1)) // recursively move left
        result = true;
    else if (mazeEscape(row, col + 1)) // recursively move right
        result = true;

    // Pick up the bread crump

    return result;

    if (maze[row][col] == '@')
        return true; 


    if (mazeEscape(row - 1, col))      // recursively move up
        return true;

    else if (mazeEscape(row + 1, col)) // recursively move down
        return true;

    else if (mazeEscape(row, col - 1)) // recursively move left
        return true;
    else if (mazeEscape(row, col + 1)) // recursively move right
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Error 1 error C2660: 'mazeEscape' : function does not take 2 arguments`

Read it.

`bool mazeEscape(char maze[ROWS][COLS],int row,int col)`

That's 3 parameters.

`if (mazeEscape(row - 1, col))`

That's 2 parameters.

2 != 3...

Comment: so am I working with the wrong data types or missing the maze array  i created

Comment: I removed an arg [code]bool mazeEscape( int row, int col){
 bool result = false;[/code]

Comment: You wrote the code to accept 3 args (maze, row, col), but you are only passing 2 (row and col)

Comment: yea I seen that I must have been tired of looking at it or something.

Answer (score 0):

You supplied this as your code base:

```
const int ROWS = 10;
const int COLS = 10;

bool mazeEscape(char maze[ROWS][COLS],int row,int col) {

    bool result = false;

    if (row < 0 || row >= ROWS || col < 0 || col >= COLS)
        return false;

    if (mazeEscape(row - 1, col))   // recursively move up
        result = true;
    else if (mazeEscape(row + 1, col)) // recursively move down
        result = true;
    else if (mazeEscape(row, col - 1)) // recursively move left
         result = true;
    else if (mazeEscape(row, col + 1)) // recursively move right
        result = true;

    // Pick up the bread crump

    return result;

    if (maze[row][col] == '@')
        return true;    

    if (mazeEscape(row - 1, col))      // recursively move up
        return true;    
    else if (mazeEscape(row + 1, col)) // recursively move down
        return true;    
    else if (mazeEscape(row, col - 1)) // recursively move left
        return true;
    else if (mazeEscape(row, col + 1)) // recursively move right
        return true;    
    else
        return false;
}
```

Each of your calls to `mazeEscape()` you are only passing two parameters to them and they appear to be the row and column values. Your function definition takes a two dimensional char array in which you are missing. Also after your first series of `if ... else if ... else statement` you are calling `return result` this will stop you from executing any of the lines that are below it. Are you intending to execute the `if` & `if...else if...else` statements below it?

Comment: Yes I went through and realized that I was working with old code along with what I had redid. I have the correct parameters and it opens but i cant seem to get the '@' symbol to function